# Trouble deciphering function parameters: pointer and pointer to pointer

Tags: c, function, pointers, syntax

I am trying to use a function meant to substitute scanf() in C. The function was written by a third party and is defined accordingly:

> ScanDecimal16uNumber - Scans a decimal 16bit unsigned number
>       ANSIC prototype: byte ScanDecimal16uNumber(const unsigned char **str, word *val)
>
> str:byte - String to scan, starting with 0x. It returns as well until where it has scanned
>
> val: Pointer to word - Pointer to value
>
> Return value:byte - Error code"

The trouble I am having is with the two inputs. After conferring with someone much more well versed in C than I am, I think I have a grasp on the second input. *val is the value I am trying to obtain (the 16bit decimal number) and val is its address. I am a bit murky on how word transitions to int, which is what I need, but feel pretty comfortable with it.

The first input is really giving me trouble, both with syntax and what it does. First off, what is the **? Its an address to an address? Of what? And how can one have an address to an address without first establishing the address by itself? How would the declaration for something like that look like?

Would really appreciate some advice both with function and syntax. I'm getting reacquainted with C and this feels a bit like the deep end.

Thanks in advance, 
Yusif Nurizade

**Update 1.0:** Ive modified the code with your suggestions and currently have no errors with just three warnings (best it's been!) I am posting the code below:

```
  const unsigned char *addressPrime                 = "0x1f307100"; 
  const unsigned char *addressOfAddressPrime        = addressPrime; 
  word                dutyCycle;                                


  PWM1_Enable();
  UTIL1_ScanDecimal16uNumber(&addressPrime, &dutyCycle);
  PWM1_SetRatio16(dutyCycle);
```

This code is being used on a Freescale FRDM KE02Z board and the new functions you are seeing are being used to control a PWM duty cycle with the value I get from the utility scan. The warnings I am getting are:

1. At the declaration for addressPrime "Pointer targets in initialization differ in signedness.

2/3. unused variables DeviceDataPrv/rtval which are part of the PWM function and I'm not   too worried about now.

My questions at this point are:

1. What is the signedness they are referring to?
2. Should I give more attention to the number I choose or does 0x1f307100 work?
3. Since this is meant to dynamically update a PWM duty cycle, should I be using a while loop for the scan function?

Comment: Inside the function, you'll probably do something like: `unsigned char const *ptr = *str;` and then scan through the string using `*ptr`; when you've reached the end of the conversion, you'll copy the current pointer back (`*str = ptr;`) before you return.

Comment: So there a string created for the scan and then that is converted to the in which is the word? That actually makes quite a bit of sense if I'm getting it right. Why the pointer to a pointer though?

Comment: Because you need to be able to modify the pointer value in the calling function — see the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19886785/15168) by [Rex Barzee](http://stackoverflow.com/users/364962/rex-barzee).

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to call the function and use the results it returns in both parameters.

```
int main(void) {
  const unsigned char *input = "0x1f30 0x7100";
  const unsigned char *p = input;
  word val1, val2;  /* A word should be the same as a uint16_t. */

  byte r = ScanDecimal16uNumber(&p, &val1);

  /* p should now point at the space between the two numbers in the
   *input string.  This will allow you to scan the next number immediately. */
  byte q = ScanDecimal16uNumber(&p, &val2);

  printf("%d %d\n", val1, val2);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Rex! To clarify, do I need the two char method to get it to work or were you just demonstrating? Also I am still unclear on how the pointer to a pointer works.

Comment: You are correct. I called the method twice only to demonstrate that it could be done. If your input string has only one number in it, then of course you will call the method once only.

Comment: The parameter that is a pointer to a pointer can be explained like this: The first asterisk allows you to pass a pointer to a string of characters. The second asterisk makes it possible for the method to return a different address than the one that you passed in.

Answer (score 0):

In C a string is defined as 'char *' (pointer to character).  So 'char **' can really just be thought of as the address of the string.  You might call it like so:

```
char *strg = "This is my String";
word aword;
ScanDecimal16uNumber(&strg, &aword);
```

This uses the & (address of) operator to send the address of the value rather than the value itself.  Does that help?

Comment: Dweeberly, 


Thanks so much for the response! It does clear up some of the issue I've been having. 


A couple of followups: I understand the char *strg but the function definition has two stars in front of the str. Was that just a typo or is it more convoluted than that? 


Also, what could the string be referring to within the bounds of the function? The word is the info I need, is the string the address to it or something else entirely?


Thanks again!

Comment: The reason they use ** is that they want to return the position of where the scan stopped, otherwise they would have just used *  Technically, this is considered a "side-effect" and not particularly desirable, but you see it a lot.  In order to return the pointer to where they stopped they have to get you to give them the pointer to that pointer so that when they change it you can get the changed point (inner char*) back.

Comment: Starting to see the light here! Could you elaborate on the position where the scan stopped? I am trying to use this position to monitor a COM port, where is the scan starting/stopping?

Comment: I'm sorry I really don't know the internal of the function, I'm going on what you posted and a lot of assuming.  The text suggests it is returning the address of where it stopped scanning, I assume because it found what it was scanning for.