# passing value from an object to a two dimensional array

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I am writing code for a simple poker game. The problem I'm having is the proper use of pointers. I did look at the link below, as well as did some google research, but I am missing something and I know its something simple. would appreciate help.

[Trouble deciphering function parameters: pointer and pointer to pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19886669/trouble-deciphering-function-parameters-pointer-and-pointer-to-pointer)

Ok i have afunction that randomly  generates the face and the value of the card. I want to pass this into an array as one string... so basically if wFace[column] is king and wSuit[row] is Heart.
i want to pass king hearts to an array..player1... I can't figure out how to do that..here is what I tried..but it only collects the first value of face..it doesnt get the suit value.

When i try the code below the error I am getting is the following
73 35 E:\C++lab\pokerGame2.cpp  [Error] incompatible types in assignment of 'const char*' to 'char* [5]'

[code]

```
void deal(const int wDeck[][13], const char *wFace[],
           const char *wSuit[], char *wplayer1[][5], const char *wplayer2[5]  )      
{   
    int card;
    int row;
    int column;
    int s;


    for(card =1; card <= 10; card++){

        if(card<=5){
            for(row = 0; row <= 3; row++){

            for(column = 0; column <= 12; column++){

                if(wDeck[row][column] ==card){
                    wplayer1[card] = wFace[column];
                    for(s=0; s<1; s++){
                        wplayer1[s] = wSuit[row];
                    }
                    //wplayer1[card][card]= (wFace[column], wSuit[row]);

                    cout<<wFace[column]<<" of "<<wSuit[row]<<"\n";
                    cout<<"player1 cards "<< wplayer1[card][s];
                }       
            }
        } 
    }
        else if(card>5 && card <=10){ 
            for(row = 0; row <= 3; row++){

            for(column = 0; column <= 12; column++){

                {if(wDeck[row][column] ==card){
                    wplayer2[card]= wFace[column], wSuit[row];
                     cout<<wFace[column]<<" of "<<wSuit[row]<<"\n";

                        }


                }
            }
        } 
    }

}

enter code here
```

[/code]

Comment: Please post small parts of code demonstrating what's not working. Also, printf takes a placeholder for a variable, it doesn't automagically concatenate what follows.

Comment: Besides the fact that you seem to be writing C code in C++, `wplayer1` and `wplayer2` are uninitialized and you then do nothing with these until you print out values from `wplayer1` at the end of `main`.

Comment: Think you ok.. from now on I will try not to include whole code..sorry..

Comment: Please format your code properly and define "does not work". What do you get and what do you expect. And why is this tagged C++ ? It's pure C.

Comment: Sorry the class im in is c++ the assignment was to take this code, and modify it so that it would deal to 2 players, and then compare there hands and determine winner.. I had no idea this was in c.. I never took c so don't know the difference..If you don't mind can you tell me what part of code is in c...I know the printf is C..try to change it to cout..but dont know how to conver all that %5s stuff to cout format...

Comment: @michael walz Im not sure what you want me to do...format it correctly???

Comment: What I mean when I say it doesnt work..is it does not display what is in the array player1...

Comment: I wish you guys would give beginners more slack..i wish there was a forumn strickly for beginners, so that asking a questiona certain way, or not using correct format wouldn't be an issue.. People come here for help and they get punnished for asking a question... This site just went from my favorite to just as bad as the rest of them..

Comment: @Darius It's kind of hard to see what you wanted to do with your code. I can only tell you why you're getting this error. First of all `wplayer2[card]= wFace[column], wSuit[row];` uses the "comma operator" it does not do concatenation as you appear to think it does (it returns the last parameter). Also, you declared `char *wplayer1[][5]` so the type of `wplayer1[s]` is `char *[5]` and the type of  `wSuit[row]` is `char *`.

Comment: So you're doing `char *[5] = char *` and the compiler is telling you that it doesn't know how to convert those types. Also, if you want to concatenate strings I'd really suggest using `std::string` as the type since otherwise you're going to have to deal with the C style `strcat` which makes memory managment a little harder.

Comment: @PeterT Thanks.. wow i have so so much to learn.. How in the world do you guys learn all of this..its so much..well im gonna try a new approach..based on using class..will edit code here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to `Stack Overflow`.

I've answered your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23073954/undefined-reference-error-to-function/23073987#23073987), where you gave the complete code so I think I do understand what you want in this post. Before I answer this question, please allow me to explain why people are so serious about the **format**.

*Format itself is not the culprit, the content is.*

If you cannot break down your question to a clean concept, it will be hard to describe it with a clean format. Digest your problem first, and then ask a clean question.

Please refer to

1. [The SSCCE - Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable),
   Example](http://www.sscce.org/), and
2. [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

It takes time to learn how to ask a good question, but trust me, it's worth your time.

Besides the fact that digesting the problem is itself a learning process, sometimes you could even find the solution yourself when trying to break it down.

Remember that `Stack Ovedrflow` is more like a **Q&A site** than a conventional forum. People here are stricter about the format. We want to see a clean, understandable question so that we can quickly answer it with less discussion (remember it's not like the conventional forum). The discussion can occur in chat rooms, or simply in the comments but the thread remains a clean form of Q&A.

---

Now let's go back to your question.

The problem is not *"how to pass two value into 2 dem array"* but *"why should you pass that kind of data?"*

Since you are using `C++`, you can use `class` to format your data.

Take a look at a simple example below:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

const char* FaceString[13] = {"Ace", "2", "3", "4",
                              "5", "6", "7", "8",
                              "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};

const char* SuitString[4] = {"Spades", "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs"};

class Card
{
public:
    int face;
    int suit;

    void toString() {
        cout<<FaceString[face]<<" of "<<SuitString[suit]<<endl;
    }

};

int main()
{    
    // Create a deck of cards
    Card deck[52];

    for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {    
        deck[i].face = i % 13;
        deck[i].suit = i % 4;    
    }

    // Shuffle
    srand (unsigned(time(0)));
    random_shuffle(&deck[0], (&deck[0]+52));   

    // Display cards
    for (int j = 0; j < 52; j++) {  
        cout<< "Card_" << (j+1) << ": ";
        deck[j].toString();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The `class Card` is an abstraction (generalization) of poker cards.

In `main()` I create a deck of card by `Card deck[52]` and assign values (face and suit) to each of them by

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++) { 
        deck[i].face = i % 13;
        deck[i].suit = i % 4;
    }
```

In this case, you can simply shuffle one-dimensional and organized objects array `deck`, and pass a whole object (a poker card with it's own face and suit parameter) as value.

I use [random_shuffle()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/random_shuffle/) in std library to shuffle the cards, and I leave dealing to you.

This will make your program cleaner and more understandable. I think this example is enough to provide you a direction of how to solve your problem.

`Stack Overflow` is a great Q&A site, it's a tremendous loss for you if you just give it up.

Keep it up, you'll get better.

Comment: Thank you Tay2510 for be patient and responding. It means a lot to me. As I do enjoy programming, but I'm not quick to grasp some of the concepts, but I I love coding. Anyways I still have a problem, The reason why I wanted to pass the data to another array, Is because I need to compare it to score each hand of the player.. So for example the cards get dealt to each player..player1, player2..player1 gets two kings a 3 and a t.. player2 gets two 5s, a 4 and a 10.. well i need to tally the pairs, or 3 of a kind etc..for each hand..and determine the winner..

Comment: So I have to store the data in an array ...player1 array, and player2 array.. If I am still thinking of this wrong please let me know...but it seems like its the only way it can be done.

Comment: It's very unwise to separate face and suit values. If you want to compare the score on each hand of the player, you can collect the face value of each card on hand with another array. It's equal to your data array, but remains the integrity of `Cards` class.

Comment: So i should put the face value in one array...and suit value in another..  example player1face..player1suit... because i have to evaluate face to get one pair, two pair, 3 of a kind.and 4 of a kind .and evaluate suits to get flush.

Comment: Yeah, the part of evaluation will be a little bit complicated. Evaluate them separately but pass them as integrity. That's what we do in real life: the pair and flush are evaluated by two different rules (face & suit), while both values are bound together in each card. I hope my example code could provide you some idea about how it works. At least it looks more readable and organized than your original one.

Comment: Can you give me a hint on how to pass 5 values from the deck into an array.. I tried to use pointers but like this...                                .       char *getCard;
 getCard = new char;                                              .for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {  
     getCard=deck[j].toString();
         }

Comment: and then pass each value from getCard to player1[] array..but i am getting the following error                                   31[Error] void value not ignored as it ought to be.....any hints on how I can do this..

Comment: im getting closer..however when i print it out it only gives me the address..not the value in the address..                                  .Card player1[5];                                                       . for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {  
     player1[j]=deck[j];
   cout<<"player1 card "<<&player1[j];
         }